# How to use different format for C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

In our project, we have C and C++ files. These files do not follow the same guidelines. Is there any way to distinguish between C and C++ in clang-format?

You can declare several languages in a .clang-format file but it does not recognize Language:C unfortunately.

Do we have to declare multiple .clang-format files in different directories (based on which language this directory contains)?

Ideally, we would like to use -style=file and be able to run clang-format on each file in our project.

Comment: It is not able to distinguish based on the source extension? Do you have `.cc` for C++ and `.c` for C?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Unfortunately, clang-format does not let me have a Language:C section, only a Cpp section. So I cannot have two styles in my .clang-format file.

Comment: Your question is not clear, but I wonder if [this page](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/it-infrastructure/mixing-c-and-cplusplus.html) will help with what you are asking.

Comment: So yeah, apparently per clang-format it does not distinguish between C and C++: *LK_Cpp (in configuration: Cpp) Should be used for C, C++, ObjectiveC, ObjectiveC++.*

Comment: A little script can do it for you though..

Comment: You should be able to use `--style=my_cpp_file_config.clang-format` for your C++ files, and `--style=my_c_file_config.clang-format` for your C files.

Comment: Make them follow the same guidelines. Even in between languages, inconsistent formatting makes things hard to read -- you have to switch back and forth.

Comment: @Eljay that command-line syntax doesn't work, at least not with the clang-format 6.0.0 that I have. The `-style` command-line option takes either the name of a pre-defined style (like `WebKit` or `Google`), or the actual style options (like `'{ColumnLimit: 80,IndentWidth: 4}`.

Comment: @EricBackus • Yes, looks like `--style=file` the `file` is literally the keyword `file` and not a metasyntactic representing a file.  In that case, `cp my_cpp_file_config.clang-format .clang-format` before running the command for C++, and `cp my_c_file_config.clang-format .clang-format` before running the command for C.